# running a useEffect after a click even if the url trigger isn't changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm following the nice article "[How to fetch data with React Hooks](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data)?", in particular the section "[ERROR HANDLING WITH REACT HOOKS](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data#error-handling-with-react-hooks)".

There we have a `useEffect` that depends on the `url` where we fetch data from.

```
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
```

The `url` is set on a `submit` from an `input`, specifying the `query` string.

```
  <form
    onSubmit={() =>
      setUrl(`http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`)
    }
  >
```

My problem is that, even if the author defines

> The error is just another state initialized with a state hook

and he implements the try/catch block for error handling and he finally concludes:

> The error state is reset every time the hook runs again. That's useful
> because after a failed request the user may want to try it again which
> should reset the error.

actually I see that the `useEffect` to fetch data depends only on the `url`, that is the `query` string, hence, if the user *doesn't change* the `query` string, he *can't try again*. This can be useful especially to try after an error, but even more in general. How to achieve this goal?
I've tried

```
    fetchData();
  }, [url, isError]);
```

but it gets stuck in a loop of updates...

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a boolean in state to track when to execute the fetchData()

```
const [loadContent, setLoadContent] = useState(true);
```

useEffect would look like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoadContent(false) // Resetting the flag
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await axios(`${url}${query}`);
      setData(result.data);

    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };
  loadContent && fetchData() // Fetch data only if the flag is true 
});
```

And finally form element like this

```
<form onSubmit={event => {
      setLoadContent(true);
      event.preventDefault();
}}>
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-lichterman-kmcw3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was

1. to add another hook state (representing the need to repeat the data fetch):

   ```
   const [repeat, setRepeat] = useState(false);
   ```
2. to make the `useEffect` dependent on it (also adding a `cleanup`):

   ```
     fetchData();
     return function cleanup() {
       setRepeat(false);
     };
   }, [url, repeat]);
   ```
3. and finally adding a check in the `submit` to force the data fetch even if the `query` string wasn't changed:

   ```
   <form onSubmit={event => {
     const before = url;
     setUrl(algoliaUrl(query));
     if  (url === before)
     {
       setRepeat(true);
     }
     event.preventDefault(); }}>
   ```